# preg_match Помогите с регулярным выражением

Tags: php

Правила таковы :
Строка должно содержать только русские и латинские буквы, и ограничивается длиной от 3 до 25 символов.
Никаких чисел или других символов кроме указных.
Если это возможно нужно еще добавить правила что строка может содержать символы қ Қ ӯ Ӯ.

У меня па лучилось такое `/^[^a-zA-Zа-ЯА-Я]{3,25}$/i` но не работает.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
^[a-zA-Zа-яА-ЯқҚӯӮёЁ]{3,25}$
```

^ в квадратных скобках исключало эти символы наоборот, так же был неверно задан диапазон. Символы были включены, как обычно. Тут https://regex101.com/ проверка прошла.

Comment: Знаете как включить эти символы қ Қ ӯ Ӯ?

Comment: `ё` - не входит в `а-я`.

Comment: Поправил, спасибо.

Comment: Спасибо за помощь